# Switching positions of two strings within a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have another question that I'd like input on, of course no direct answers just something to point me in the right direction!

I have a string of numbers ex. 1234567890 and I want 1 & 0 to change places (0 and 9) and for '2345' & '6789' to change places. For a final result of '0678923451'.

First things I did was convert the string into a list with:

```
ex. original = '1234567890'
    original = list(original)
    original = ['0', '1', '2' etc....]
```

Now, I get you need to pull the first and last out, so I assigned

```
x = original[0]
```

and

```
y = original[9]
```

So: x, y = y, x (which gets me the result I'm looking for)

But how do I input that back into the original list?

Thanks!

Comment: hint: consider `s = "12345"` and `print s[1:4]`. slicing operator is a friend for you.

Comment: You don't really need to go long way by making lists out of string.. You can use slicing notations. Example, original[:1] will give you first character. Search about them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you 'pulled' the data from the list in variables x and y doesn't help at all, since those variables have no connection anymore with the items from the list. But why don't you swap them directly:

```
original[0], original[9] = original[9], original[0]
```

You can use the slicing operator in a similar manner to swap the inner parts of the list.

But, there is no need to create a list from the original string. Instead, you can use the slicing operator to achieve the result you want. Note that you cannot swap the string elements as you did with lists, since in Python strings are immutable. However, you can do the following:

```
>>> a = "1234567890"
>>> a[9] + a[5:9] + a[1:5] + a[0]
'0678923451'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks! So to get it back to a str after I finish everything, I would: return print(''.join(original)) right?

Comment: Yes. But again, you don't need the list at all. You can just do what I did on the string.

Comment: I tried doing it with just the string, but I'm getting a 'str' object does not support item assignment.